# Mongodb: Query on the last N documents(some portion) of a collection only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In my collection that has say 100 documents, I want to run the following query:

```js
collection.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "some_string"})
```

Assume that a suitable "text" index already exists and thus my question is : **How can I run this query on the last 'n' documents only?**

All the question that I found on the web ask how to *get* the last n docs. Whereas My question is how to *search* on the last n docs only?

More generally my question is How can I run a mongo query on some portion say 20% of a collection.

**What I tried**

Im using pymongo so I tried to use skip() and limit() to get the last n documents but I didn't find a way to perform a query on cursor that the above mentioned function return.

After @hhsarh's anwser here's what I tried to no avail

```py
# here's what I tried after initial answers
recents = information_collection.aggregate([
                {"$match" : {"$text" : {"$search" : "healthline"}}},
                {"$sort" : {"_id" : -1}},
                {"$limit" : 1},
            ])
```

The result is still coming from the whole collection instead of just the last record/document as the above code attempts.

The last document doesn't contain "healthline" in any field therefore the intended result of the query should be empty []. But I get a documents.

Please can someone tell how this can be possible

Comment: Does anyone have a better answer?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can be achieved using MongoDB Aggregation

Note: As pointed out by @turivishal, `$text` won't work if it is not in the first stage of the aggregation pipeline.

```js
collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10  // `n` value, where n is the number of last records you want to consider
  },
  {
    "$match" : {
      // All your find query goes here
    }
  },
], {allowDiskUse=true})  // just in case if the computation exceeds 100MB
```

Since `_id` is indexed by default, the above aggregation query should be faster. But, its performance reduces in proportion to the `n` value.

Note: Replace the last line in the code example with the below line if you are using `pymongo`

```py
], allowDiskUse=True)
```

Comment: query is not valid, The `$match` stage that includes a `$text` must be the first stage in the pipeline. see [$text restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions)

Comment: yes, that's because you have to add the key you want to search in place of `$match`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Please share the complete key name and the value you want to search for

Comment: I am not OP, and if i am not wrong OP wants to use [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text) search (operators), or you can wait for his response.

Comment: oops. very sorry

Comment: @hhharsha36 I tried the query and I still  got the documents from the entire collection instead from within my specified limit. I tried $text search

Comment: Have you tried changing the limit value in `$limit` stage?

Comment: @hhharsha36 Yes I tried many numbers including 1, wherein trying to consider just the last doc. is it not working  because I moved $match to first in pipeline for $text query?

Comment: @cosmicsage No, `$match` or `$text` should be after the `$sort` and `$limit` pipeline stages (in the same order) as I have showcased in the example. I have updated the answer with your `$match` query

Comment: @turivishal cosmicage wants to apply this `$text` operator on the last `n` records. I don't think it will work if we apply the `$text` pipeline as the first stage. I don't know if I am missing something. I am still not getting it. Maybe PM me?

Comment: there is a restriction by mongodb you can use $text operator only and only in first stage, and you have used it in third stage, so its invalid, it will throw an error. *$match with $text is only allowed as the first pipeline stage*

Comment: ok, I got it now. My answer is wrong. Thanks for pointing it out. Guess `$text` has to be abandoned in the `$match` stage. Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text) operator, because there is a restriction,

> *The `$match` stage that includes a `$text` must be the first stage in the pipeline*

It means we can't limit documents before `$text` operator, read more about [$text operator restriction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions).

---

Second option this might possible if you use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) regular expression operator instead of `$text` operator for searching,

And if you need to search same like `$text` operator you have modify your search input as below:

- lets assume `searchInput` is your input variable
- list of search field in `searchFields`
- slice that search input string by space and loop that words array and convert it to regular expression
- loop that search fields `searchFields` and prepare `$in` condition

```py
searchInput = "This is search"
searchFields = ["field1", "field2"]
searchRegex = []
searchPayload = []

for s in searchInput.split(): searchRegex.append(re.compile(s, re.IGNORECASE));
for f in searchFields: searchPayload.append({ f: { "$in": searchRegex } })
print(searchPayload)
```

Now your input would look like,

```
[
  {'field1': {'$in': [/This/i, /is/i, /search/i]}}, 
  {'field2': {'$in': [/This/i, /is/i, /search/i]}}
]
```

Use that variable `searchPayload` with `$or` operator in search query at last stage using `$in` operator,

```py
recents = information_collection.aggregate([
  # 1 = ascending, -1 descending you can use anyone as per your requirement
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }, 
  # use any limit of number as per your requirement
  { "$limit": 10 }, 
  { "$match": { "$or": searchPayload } }
])

print(list(recents))
```

> **Note:** The `$regex` regular expression search will cause performance issues.

To improve search performance you can create a compound index on your search fields like,

```
information_collection.createIndex({ field1: 1, field2: 1 });
```

Comment: Is this the best method?

Comment: there is no any other method to fulfil your requirement in single query, i can not say this is best method for your project requirement.

Comment: thanks for your effort. I decided to use an intermediary collection in the project. Mongo might someday support a feature for this.